# What is the formal term referred to here in this introductory chapter on differential geometry?

Tags: differential-geometry, terminology

For context, this is an old MEI A-Level textbook (UK), titled "Further Pure 3" i.e. the most challenging textbook for the further math A-level that there was. The article referred to I have not been able to find for free, and I would dearly like to know what they are alluding to when they say "reasonably smooth" curves and what the mysterious exact definition is!

[image: textbook screenshot]

Comment: Well, have you tried looking up that article in the footnote? I don't know about this particular definition, but often when mathematicians say things like "reasonably smooth" they mean it is $k$-times differentiable for some $k$ that's high enough.

Comment: @JairTaylor I did look it up but it seemed to be behind a paywall... I would also expect that a simpler definition such as $k$-times differentiable would be within the scope of the book and included

Comment: I'd guess they mean the curve is a "smooth manifold" of dimension 1. You might try looking at some introductory differential geometry books such as [Elementary Differential Geometry](https://www.amazon.com/Elementary-Differential-Geometry-Revised-2nd/dp/0120887355) by O'Neill ; I believe that book will have a precise definition.

Comment: For reference, the (paywalled) article is here: https://www.jstor.org/stable/3617131

Comment: @HansLundmark Thank you!